# Looking for program execution file location!

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a program running only by using right clicking.

How can we find the location of the that source file? I believe im looking for .exe extension. The folder where i installed it don't have the .exe file on that program and many .dll files. is there a possibility that it was running by those .dll file?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the image using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx?ppud=4).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that windows task manager can give you this data:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> and start task manager;
Find your process from the list on the processes tab;
Right click and select *open file location*

Seems to me your question might be more appropriate to one of the related forums (serverfault?)